# How to resolve line continuation problem in python?

Tags: python

I want to continue line on the next line but error "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character" occures. What s the problem? help please

```
df_fp = pd.concat([ \
  mdf['Заявитель'], \
  mdf['Название'],\
  mdf['Номер заявки'],\ 
  mdf['Дата приоритета'], \ 
  mdf['Дата публикации']], axis = 1)
```

I tried to paste spaces before slashes, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is not valid Python. Your example should be like:

```py
df_fp = pd.concat(
    [
        mdf["Заявитель"],
        mdf["Название"],
        mdf["Номер заявки"],
        mdf["Дата приоритета"],
        mdf["Дата публикации"],
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```